# ipython notebook rmagic extension blank lines in output

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

When I run any %R code with ipython notebook (windows version), the output contains a 480 x 480 blank image before the result. I have applied the [fix #2433](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/2533) to get rmagic to work on windows - not sure that this has anything to do with the blank image output, though. Can anyone help with this?

This is what the output looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem. My work-around was to pass '-h 1 -w 1', so at least the returned blank is small. It would be nice if '-n' handled this.